# Use Array.filter on object array in observable

Tags: angular

I want add `filter` on my object array. I try this :

```
this.projects
      .pipe(
          map(arr => {
              console.error(arr);
              arr.filter(r => r.name == 'x')
          })
      )
      .subscribe(result => console.log('Filter results:', result))
```

My `console.error` return my array but when I `console.log` in my `subscribe` I have `undefined`. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I would prefer @Bear Nithi's solution, I'll show you the bug in your code. Well, you should `return arr.filter(r => r.name == 'x')` in your `map()` call, like this:

```
this.projects
      .pipe(
          map(arr => {
              console.error(arr);
              return arr.filter(r => r.name == 'x') // here, return filtered array
          })
      )
      .subscribe(result => console.log('Filter results:', result))
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `Array.filter` method, you should use buit-in [`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) operator in `rxjs`

```
this.projects
      .pipe(
         filter(r => r.name == 'x')
      )
      .subscribe(result => console.log('Filter results:', result))
```